# CheckBox in xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, checkbox, components

Hello for all programmers and development-fans!
I want to implement checkbox to my mobile application, but get next
[picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA9ut.png). Why?  [Microsoft manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/checkbox) says, it's possible and no hint than Xamarin.Forms don't have any CheckBoxes. Environment Visual Studio 2017. There are fresh updates.

CheckBox component isn't detected in my environment neither in xaml nor in c# code.
In some hours I've found Editor-component doesn't have property IsReadOnly, but has to. That's why I suspect it's nesessary to update

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images.  Are you actually getting a compiler error when you build?  A blue squiggle in the IDE does not provide any useful information about what the problem is.

Comment: I didn't send the code, but illustration of IDE underline which shows impossibilty CheckBox definition while another component (as Label) defines correctly. My environment is set for another language that's why I might give wrong formulation, but it is trivial ("Type or name CheckBox namespace doesn't exist in the namespace Xamarin.Forms")

Comment: Which version of XF are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by updating Xamarin.Forms in NuGet. Ver 5.0 has CheckBox